# Why does my laptop suspend after 5 minutes?

Tags: suspend, power-management

If I leave my Lenovo G50 laptop open, regardless if it is pluged-in or not, it suspends after 5 minutes and I have to wake it up. Of course I checked the power options and have it at "Don't suspend" on both plugged and unplugged. I have the latest 16.02 LTS from Ubuntu. So what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you checked the power options screen so I'll put add this one even though I don't think it is effecting you, but which you can check nonethelesss:

[image]

The only thing I can think of now are gnome settings which you can force off via the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type nothing
```

The value of `0` seconds on lines 1 and 3 turns the function off. The `nothing` feature on lines 2 and 4 are like hitting it was a hammer twice.

If problem persists there are other things in `systemd` to look at such as `xautolock` but the steps above are the most obvious ones to try first.

Comment: Can't believe i was that dumb. Forgot about screen and lock settings. That was the issue. Thank you so much, I thumbed you up, but my rep is too low.

Comment: @LiviuVarlam No worry about thumbs up but you can click the check mark next to the answer to let others know it solves the problem. Thanks.